# Why does FFMPEG work in terminal but not in php with exec()?

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

I am trying to get FFMPEG to work in php. I just installed ffmpeg and x264 and ran the following command in my terminal:

```
$command = 'ffmpeg -i /home/gman/Desktop/cave.wmv -acodec libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0 /home/gman/Desktop/newvideo.flv
```

It worked perfectly and created a new flv video from the inital video, just like I wanted.

Now when I try the same thing in php, nothing happens...

```
$safe_path = escapeshellarg("/home/gman/Desktop/newvideo.flv");
$command = 'ffmpeg -i /home/gman/Desktop/cave.wmv -acodec libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0 ' . $safe_path;
exec($command);
```

Anyone have any ideas? Can I somehow see what exec is doing and see some sort of output? Would appreciate it.

Comment: You can pass a variable as second argument to `exec()` and the output is assigned to it.

Comment: Use http://php.net/shell_exec instead to have the output returned in a string.

Comment: What Alex and Brad said, then come back and post the results so we can help out! :)

Comment: If this is a shell script, then `system()` is another good option which will print all output to stdout directly without any extra effort.

Comment: No, there is no error dialogue, I tried shell_exec, like so and got nothing $command = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i /home/geoff/Desktop/cave.wmv -acodec libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0 ' . $safe_path);
echo $command;

Comment: I tried using system() and return value was 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.codyjung.com/2011/05/29/problems-with-lampp-and-exec/

My solution was to simply copy the ones from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu and overwrite the LAMPP ones. Could that cause problems later? Maybe, but I guess we’ll deal with that when it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you are calling ffmpeg in an exec you need to put in the absolute path to ffmpeg eg:

```
$safe_path = escapeshellarg("/home/gman/Desktop/newvideo.flv");
$command = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/gman/Desktop/cave.wmv -acodec libfaac -aq 100 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -threads 0 ' . $safe_path;
exec($command);
```

Comment: Another factor may be the permissions on the folder you are writing to. Make sure you have the correct write permissions.

Comment: see I thought that too, but I just ran the same command in a terminal and it wrote to desktop just fine

Comment: It would depend how you are running the command via php. If you are running it through apache, and it doesn't have permission to write to that folder it will fail. If when running the command in terminal, you are the owner of desktop then it will run fine.

Comment: how can you tell if apache has permission?

Comment: when you "ls -l" in /home/gman/ what does it say beside Desktop?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  3 geoff geoff 4096 2011-06-05 22:18 Desktop

Comment: try

chmod 777 /home/gman/Desktop

Then run the script again and see if it worked.

Comment: hmm thanks again, didn't work, it is like the script is not even executing because it just instantly completes...

Comment: I tried executing the file in the terminal by using 'php testing.php' and it worked fine...Any more ideas?

Comment: found this error in my error log /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)